# Add new menu in SocialEngine admin panel

Tags: menu, admin, socialengine

How can I add a new menu for admin panel(not front site) in SocialEngine?
Am I supposed to use database and its tables only?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The admin panel is restricted to what you see. It doesn't have the same flexibility as the frontend. Depending on what you want to add, you might have to do it in the Database or you can add a static link in the tpl file. If you give more information I might be able to direct you on how to accomplish your requirement.